# How to get each email address in boxed? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get each e-mail address typed in input?
Everything works correctly, except the design in the input

It looks like this in the post box, not html format:

```
<span class="emBox">hello@world.org</span>, <span class="emBox">stack@overflow.org</span>,
```

javascript:

```
    var textarea = $('#emails');

     textarea.on({
    keyup: function(e) {
        if (e.which === 188) check();
    },
    blur: check    
});

function check() {
    var val  = $.trim(textarea.val()),
        err  = '';

    if (!val.length) {
        err = 'No input ?';
        return;
    }

    var emails   = val.split(','),
        notvalid = [],
        temp     = [];

    $.each(emails, function(_,mail) {
        mail = $.trim(mail);
        if ( mail.length ) {
            var m = mail.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
            if (m) {
                temp.push('<span class="emBox">' + m + '</span>');
            }else{
                temp.push(mail);
                notvalid.push(mail)
            }
        }else{
            temp.push(mail);
        }
        if (notvalid.length) err = 'Not valid emails : ' + notvalid.join(', ');
    });

    $('#error').html(err);
    textarea.val((temp.length ? temp : '' + emails + "").join(', '));
    }
```

Example:

[image]

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/x7fj81uL/6/)

Comment: I didn't get what you want. Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @AnisR. Hi, html code appears in input. Only plain text.. I've asked him how to do HTML rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are doing is just inserting **plain text** inside a text area.

To make these render as HTML, have a container div:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

And insert the spans inside the div's innerHTML:

```
var div = document.getElementById("container");
div.innerHTML = (temp.length ? temp : '' + emails + "").join(', '));
```

Comment: I'm talking about HTML rendering in Input [example](https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Tiny-Text-Field-Based-Tags-Input-Plugin-For-jQuery-Tagify.jpg)